# Método save() do eloquent não funciona

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.1

Quando tento utilizar o método `save()` do eloquent-laravel 5.1, da maneira que pede a documentação, a atualização não é feita no banco.

Esse é como pede a documentação:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);    
$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';    
$flight->save();
```

Esse é o meu:

```
public function adotado($id) {         
        $animal = Animal::find($id); 
        if (Auth::user()->id == $animal->user_id) {
            $animal->ativo = 0;
            $animal->save();
            return redirect()->action('UserController@index');
        } else {
            return view('errors.restrito');
        }
    }
```

Verifiquei com `dd($animal)` que os dados estão sendo puxados normalmente do banco após o `find()`, inclusive o atributo 'ativo' é igual a 1. Dentro do `if`, `dd($animal->ativo)` retorna 0, ou seja, até ali o código está ok. O `dd($animal->save())` também retorna true e é redirecionado normalmente para o index, porém, a atualização não aparece no db.

Alguma dica? Salve-me quem puder. Grato.

Comment: Tente comentar o redirect e verifique se acontece algum erro

Comment: Nenhum erro. =\

Comment: Verifica o retorno do `save`, pode estar retornando `false`. Seria o método `push` útil nesse caso?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a alteração está sendo feita no $animal->ativo que está 1 no db. Depois que setei ativo = 0 dentro do if, o retorno de dd($animal->ativo) era 0, logo teve alteração.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o retorno do save() é 1. Tentei push também e continuou na mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Na view, ao marcar o animal como **"adotado"**, um **modal** era exibido pedindo confirmação. Após retirar o modal da view, o save() funcionou normalmente.
A pergunta que me ficou é: **por quê?**

O 'confirmar' do modal exibia o caminho **'animal/adotado/6'** onde 6 é o id do animal. Exatamente da mesma maneira feito sem modal. Na action, confirmei que recebia o $id das duas maneiras, com ou sem modal. A diferença é que de um jeito não fazia alteração e do outro sim. Sou iniciante e não sei por que isso aconteceu, e talvez nem seja uma resposta adequada, mas tirando o modal da view resolveu.

Answer (score 1):

Não use redirect()->action() amigo. Crie rotas para seus métodos, ficará muito mais simples.

Alguns passos para solucionar:

1. Use try/catch nos teus métodos, e coloque um dump() na exception.
2. Todos os erros são armazenados no arquivo laravel.log, que fica no
   diretório storage/logs/laravel.log. Você pode verificar por ali o
   porque não está salvando.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Irei utilizá-la.